# android studio 4.2 unable to install android sdk

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-manager

I have installed android studio 4.2 on windows 10
after removing's it
but [image: unable to install android sdk] it always show me as in been installed
I already try uninstall and removing all android folders
in program files and user files
and then install fresh but still tell me it is installed
any help would be appreciated

Comment: what will happen if you press `Next` ? Whats problem?

Comment: nothing is installed

Comment: have you removed `C:\Users\mahye\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` folder?

Comment: yes, I removed it

Answer (score 0):

after many trying and searching for solution I found that by changed the regional setting to English solve this problem.